# How to Install aws-sam-cli in ubuntu 14?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I want to update aws-sam-cli on my ubuntu 14.04. I have sam 0.2.11 version. I want to update in 0.3.0. When I run

```
pip install --user aws-sam-cli
```

or

```
pip install --user --upgrade aws-sam-cli
```

I got

> Downloading/unpacking aws-sam-cli
>     Downloading aws-sam-cli-0.3.0.tar.gz (128kB): 128kB downloaded
>     Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip_build_amber/aws-sam-cli/setup.py) egg_info for package aws-sam-cli
>       /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
>         warnings.warn(msg)
>       error in aws-sam-cli setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py:267: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'python_requires'
>     warnings.warn(msg)
>   error in aws-sam-cli setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers
>
> Cleaning up...
>   Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_amber/aws-sam-cli
>   Storing debug log for failure in /home/amber/.pip/pip.log**

Comment: having similar problem in os x, not able to find anything on it...

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and here's how I installed aws-sam-cli

Make sure you uninstall aws-sam-local if you have an older version with

```
npm uninstall -g aws-sam-local
```

Then run

```
pip install --user --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
pip install --user --upgrade aws-sam-cli
```

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade `pip` and `setuptools`:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools
```

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling the old version and reinstall it again using the following commands.

npm uninstall -g aws-sam-local

pip install --user aws-sam-cli

If both don't work for you then you can download the source directly from the GitHub repository  and use it. you can find the repository at https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases

Comment: I don't think there are binaries there, just source code